# Getting duplicate output

Tags: bash, scripting, sh

I'm trying to write a bash script that looks for a file in one directory and replaces it with one of the same name from a source directory. When I run the `find` command, it seems to be setting my `$path` twice

```bash
 for f in build-res/$1/*.png; do
     file="$(basename "$f")"
     echo "Looking for $file in $TMP"
     path="$(find $TMP -type f -name "$file")"
     if [[ -z $path ]]; then
             echo "Could not find $file in $TMP"
      else
             echo "Replacing file at $path with $file"
             echo "__path__"
             echo $path
             echo "---"
      fi
 done
```

Running one iteration of this loop outputs something like

```
Replacing file at tmp/trx//images/background/background_iphone5.png
tmp/trx//images/background_iphone5.png with background_iphone5.png
__path__
tmp/trx//images/background/background_iphone5.png tmp/trx//images/background_iphone5.png
---
```

Notice how path repeats itself with a space between. Why would this be happening?

Another note, why is it coming back with `//` in the path as well? This doesn't seem to be an issue, more so just curious.

Comment: That's not the same path twice. That's two different paths.

Comment: The double `//` probably comes directly from the value of `TMP`; how does it get set?

Comment: You may want to replace `path` with an array, `path=( $(find $TMP -type f -name "$file") )` which allows you to test the number of matches returned `[ ${#path[@]} -gt 1 ] && handle multiples...`

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin. I was just debating between ignoring dupes and handling them somehow. I think you just answered that debate

Comment: @chepner TMP gets set from an argument passed into the script which is first set as SRC=$1 then TMP=tmp/SRC. Typing this out, I see my issue. SRC is prepended / already. So that answers that

Comment: @Chris, you really can't ignore them because you need some way of isolating which file you will copy, etc.. At least with an array, if you don't handle them in some fancy way, you can always just use `${path[0]}` `:p`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely this is not the same path:

```
tmp/trx//images/background/background_iphone5.png tmp/trx//images/background_iphone5.png
```

-->

```
tmp/trx//images/background/background_iphone5.png 
tmp/trx//images/background_iphone5.png
```

This is the result output of `find` which finds 2 files with the same name in different subdirectories of `/tmp`.

Just FYI, if you want to control how deep `find` can descend into subdirs, there's an option for that:

> -maxdepth levels
>
> Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the command line arguments. -maxdepth 0 means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.

Or if you want just a single result you can use

> -quit
>
> Exit immediately. No child processes will be left running, but no more paths specified on the command line will be processed. For example, `find /tmp/foo /tmp/bar -print -quit` will print only `/tmp/foo`.

Comment: I guess I just need a second set of eyes to realize it's finding more than one file -__-. Thank you

Comment: Right, that happens to all of us =)